# Trying to check if all query inside foreach echo none result, php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Look at my code, I use foreach to get value from a query result, then use each value to get a query result, if $sql2 echo something, then it will run. But how about if none of of $sql2 echo a result, then I want to do something else outside the foreach loop? how to check if no $sql2 result at all?

```
<?php
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT whatever FROM table where v=%s ",$test));

foreach($sql as $val){
        $dis1 = $val-> whatever;
        $sql2 = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT wherever from table where val=%s
        ",$dis1));
       if(sql2){
       /*  do something here*/
         }
    }
     /* if() every sql2 echo empty result
         then do something else
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable early and update it in the loop if something is echoed. At the end, check if it has been updated

```
$echoed = false;
$sql = $wpdb...

foreach($sql as $val){
   ...
   if($sql2){
       $echoed = true; //update, so you will know later that something was echoed
       ...
   }
}
if(!$echoed){
   // nothing was echoed
}
```